# Can I reference the MSI output from a WiX Setup project in my wix Bootstrapper project?

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.7

For example, I want to do this, but it generates an error:

```
<Chain>
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.SetupProjectWiX.TargetPath)" />
</Chain>
```

- where `SetupProjectWiX` is my MSI WiX project.

I do something similar when creating the MSI itself, and figured the above was possible. Here's the MSI creation referencing a VS project

```
<File Source="$(var.uCamera.TargetPath)" />
```

**Edit:**

I had not added the MSI project as a reference in the bootstrapper project - now it works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. the same [project referencing and variables](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/votive_project_references.htm) techniques apply to Bootstrapper projects, too.

Comment: But when I reference the MSI package, as shown in my OP `$(var.SetupProjectWiX.TargetPath)`, it fails to build the bootstrapper - no error that I can see in the Output :(
When I reference the project using the actual path it's fine.

Comment: You didn't show the _project reference_ (i.e., text from the bootstrapper .wixproj); You did show the _variable_ reference. The variable is not defined unless the project reference exists. Did you miss that step?

Comment: Certainly did! Thank youuuuuuuuuu!